# How to find minimum number of locomotives to cover maximum miles in a network?

Tags: optimization

I have a freight train dataset with details like locomotive type, substations it passes through, trip date, travel miles, etc. There are 5 locomotive types in the dataset, and each type has 20-30 locos. I want to find out how many locomotives I should choose from each type, to map out the entire network (max miles under each substation). What would be the best approach for this task?

Comment: start by defining your variables. For example, let $x_{ijk}$ be a binary variables that takes value $1$ iff loco $i$ of type $j$ covers leg $k$ of the network (this is just an example, you might need to define your problem with more details).

Comment: To add on to what @Kuifje said, we're happy to help if you get stuck with your model, and if you ask specific questions. As it's stated now, though, your question might be a bit too broad for us to provide good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will request help if i am stuck anywhere when building my model.